# schema.org json-ld using coldfusion

Tags: json, coldfusion, json-ld

I have not used json with coldfusion hence looking for some advice. I am trying to use coldfusion to get the schema.org json-ld work on a website. I have a query coming from a component which has the data that needs to go in the json. Can someone give me a gist of what needs to be done in order to spit out the json from the query in the below script tags on the page. Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="application/ld+json"></script>
```

Comment: Are you in control of the component?

Comment: Yes i am in control

Comment: Does `serializeJSON(myQuery,'struct')` get you where you need to go?  https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html

Comment: The schema JSON is case-sensitive and specific, so you wan't be able to serialize a CFQuery to generate it.  (Make sure that you use notation like `myStruct["faxNumber"] = FaxNumber;`.)  I recently wrote a CFTag to generate Schema JSON for embedding in webpages based on our internal CMS.  I recommend using this markup generator to view the various types of markup: https://www.jamesdflynn.com/json-ld-schema-generator/

Comment: Ok can I see the cftag that creates it?

Comment: @JamesMoberg - I learn something new every day.   Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this [JSON-LD Schema Markup Generator](https://www.jamesdflynn.com/json-ld-schema-generator/) to determine the fields and schema to use and then created a ColdFusion struct that matched it. For some elements (addresses, social media URLs, multiple locations), you'll need to create an array-of-structs.

There are many optional parameters you can add to each markup type, so it's difficult to program a one-size-fits-all solution. *(I finally managed to write a custom tag that works specifically with our internal/custom CMS to auto-generate this for our client webpages.)*

Here's a bare-bones ColdFusion sample for type "WebSite".  *(We've been adding inlining the JSON to the same webpage.)*

```
<cfscript>
SchemaData = {
  "@context" = "http://www.schema.org",
  "@type" = "WebSite",
  "name" = "My Website",
  "alternateName" = "My Alternate Website Title (optional)",
  "url" = "https://www.mywebsite.com/"
};
writeoutput('<script type="application/ld+json">#SchemaData#</script>');
</cfscript>
```

Comment: OK, so I should be just able to add the json inline for the entity i am working with right

Comment: Yes.  After embedding Schema JSON on a webpage, you can test the validity by entering the URL using Google's "Structured Data Testing Tool" and manually reviewing the results.
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/

Comment: Can you give an example of multiple locations scenario in the above case, i keep getting an error on the json.

Comment: A sample of the source JSON for multiple locations can be viewed here. https://intuitivedigital.com/2016/10/json-ld-for-multiple-locations/  _(It's an array of single "address" structs.  It can become complex if you need to pass different contact info & hours for each location.)_

Comment: ok thanks, what is the difference if i just put the json inline directly, inside <script type="application/ld+json"></script> without using <cfscript>? Please bear with me, i am just trying to learn as i go and have not done this before.

Comment: You can use `CFOUTPUT`. `cfscript` w/`WriteOutput` is the non-tagbased version.  Just ensure that the JSON is outputted within the HTML "application/ld+json" script tags on your webpage.  (If you aren't dynamically generating this from a database, ColdFusion isn't even needed and you can have static JSON code in the CFM file.)